# What is Amsterdam city center and transportation from there to Leiden?

Tags: public-transport, netherlands, amsterdam

I will arrive to Amsterdam on 17:30 local time.

my accommodation is on **Leiden CS**, I know there is a train from Amsterdam airport to Leiden, but I am thinking that I want to visit the city center first.

So my questions are:

What is the city center? how to get there from the airport and then how to go from the city center to Leiden CS?

I will just use public transportation so I appreciate if you tell me the last travel of the trains

#### Update

According to my research

[image]

I put three stars on the map, the one in the top is the old center (maybe it is the most popular place in Amsterday), the one in the middle is the airport, the one at the bottom is Leiden.

So I have to go from the airport to the old center, and then from the old center to the airport.

I don't know if public transporation is avaible, do you help please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Schiphol airport, you can take a train to Amsterdam Centraal. From there you can also get a direct connection to Leiden Centraal.

You can use the [Nationale Spoorwegen (*National Railways*) website](http://www.ns.nl/) to plan your trip accordingly. They offer an English version of the site.

[image: Nationale Spoorwegen planner]

If you are also looking for additional public transportation time tables, for example to use trams or buses, you can use [the 9292 Openbaar Vervoer (*Public Transportation*) website](http://9292.nl/). They also offer an English version.

[image: 9292 Openbaar Vervoer planner]

The best thing about 9292 is that it allows you to plan trips with multiple types of transportation, meaning you can simply enter your starting point and destination and it will present you with all public transportation timetables, including trains, trams, buses, etc.

You can go as far as simply entering addresses and the planner will tell you how many minutes to walk to a bus stop, how long on the bus, how long walking to the train station, when to transfer, walking to a tram station, and finally walking to your destination address.

Both sites also display updated delays.

[image: 9292 planning]

Comment: This is http://9292.nl/en/journeyadvice/station-amsterdam-centraal/leiden_vitruviusstraat/departure/2016-07-03T2158 where I go (the street vitruviusstraat in Leiden. the link states that i have to use bus 187, do you know the last bus please ?

Comment: You can find the last bus by just entering a random late time and see what it gives. It looks like the 187 leaving Leiden centraal station 23:35 is the last one. There are some more buses you can use, till just after midnight, but with a longer walk.

Comment: You can see your current times, and also what times it would be if you take a train earlier or later. Keep picking a later departure until you see no more buses will arrive in time. In your example, your latest arrival time is 0:00. If you pick a later departure, you will arrive at 5 am in the morning (the first arrival of the day).

Answer (score 5):

The city center is indeed near Amsterdam Centraal. There are multiple trains going there from the airport. It is about a 15 minute train ride. The right platform is signed quite clearly. Be careful to not take the train to Amsterdam RAI or Amsterdam Bijlmer ArenA, these are not the town center.

To go from Amsterdam to Leiden, you can take two different routes. Both will show Leiden CS on the sign and take equally long, so this won't matter. One goes through Haarlem, one through the airport.

You can plan your route at any time on 9292.nl. The trains you need go all day, although less frequently during nighttime.

You need a OV-chipkaart to take public transportation in the Netherlands. You can buy a single-use one at every train station, but these are not usable in other public transportation. It may be worth investing in a card of your own. [Check the OV-chipkaart website to find out which card is best for you](https://www.ov-chipkaart.nl/apply-1/which-card-is-right-for-you.htm).

Comment: Thanks, in Leiden CS (which i think is the same as Leiden Centraal, correct me if i am wrong please) i have to take a bus, do you know a website for the busses to see the last bus avaiable ?

Comment: @user2059935 Not sure if you've seen [my answer](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/72354/11297) but you can use the 9292 website for that.

Comment: CS is short for 'Centraal Station', it is the same station. The same is true for Amsterdam Centraal and train stations in other cities.